# Comparing integer values of 2 or more keys of one hashmap to 2 values in another hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two hashmaps (resources and neededResources).
Goal is to reduce the amount of resources hashmap, but that can only happen if it has enough of both resource.

```
// String = name of resources available
// Integer = amount of resources available
Map<String, Integer> resources = new HashMap<>();
resources.put("gold", 10);
resources.put("silver", 10);
// String = name of resource needed
// Integer = amount of resource needed
Map<String, Integer> neededResources = new HashMap<>();
neededResources.put("gold", 2);
neededResources.put("silver", 3);
```

In this sample case, it would take resources 3 times since on 4th try there wouldn't be enough silver, gold value doesn't change as well.

I'm a novice at Java. So far I've tried iterating through both of them but it becomes hard to read and my attempts have looked way too difficult for this task.

Comment: I can't understand what you need to do. Given the setup you describe, what should the result be? The number 3? Why? Because it is smaller than 5?

Comment: As a result 3 objects that require these resources would be created. One object requires all resources given in neededResources. It can't make 4 objects even though it has enough gold but there aren't enough silvers. These resource names are just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you are after. The code can be inserted after your setup code.

Find the number of possible expenditures:

```
int n = resources.entrySet().stream().mapToInt(entry -> entry.getValue()/neededResources.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0)).min().getAsInt();
System.out.println(n);
```

Prints 3

Spend it:

```
resources.replaceAll((k,v) -> v-n*neededResources.getOrDefault(k,0));
System.out.println(resources);
```

Prints {gold=4, silver=1}

Comment: The first solution for finding n works great for my use case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @kaleh I changed the code a bit after Arkadiys suggestions.

Comment: @kaleh Could you upvote this? It really bugs me that the solution you used is the lowest ranked.

Comment: I did upvote but upvotes by people with less than 15 rep aren't publicly visible, sorry.

Comment: I reached 15 rep so I could upvote and mark it as solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take the value from your resources map, substract the value from neededResources and check if it is >=0. This tells you that there were at least as many resources available as needed. If resources were available, update the value. Otherwise dont.

Create a method wrapper in your resources class

```
public boolean hasResources(String... pResources){
  for(String resourceKey : pResources){
  int newValue = resources.get(pResourceKey) - neededResources.get(pResourceKey);
    if(newValue < 0){
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

public void takeResources(String... pResources){
  for(String resourceKey : pResources){
  int newValue = resources.get(pResourceKey) - neededResources.get(pResourceKey);
    resources.put(resourceKey, newValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: @karleh create a method for it which has the resource key passed as a string. Java basics.... I updated my answer for you. Method returns true if resources were available, false if not. Use takeResources afterwards to actuall remove them from the map

Answer (score 1):

The key to this problem is that we don't want to modify the `resources` `Map` unless we are absolutely sure that it contains all of the `resourcesNeeded`.  Once you learn about `Stream`s in Java, this problem should simplify.

First, we want to check if the `resources` `Map` contains all of the keys in the `resourcesNeeded` `Map`, which may or may not already be given information which you haven't mentioned.

```
resources.keySet().containsAll(neededResources.keySet());
```

If that condition is `false`, then we know that there are needed resources that are not available.  Otherwise, we can now check if every value in `resources` is greater than or equal to the value in `resourcesNeeded` for its respective key:

```
resources.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .allMatch(entry -> entry.getValue() >= resourcesNeeded.get(entry.getKey()));
```

If that condition is `false`, then more resources are needed then are currently available.  Otherwise, we can now modify `resources`, essentially subtracting each respective value in `resourcesNeeded`:

```
resources.replaceAll((k, v) -> v - resourcesNeeded.getOrDefault(k, 0)));
```

The last two statements can be placed inside of a loop to ensure that the minimum amount of resources remain.

Comment: I keep getting "get(java.lang.Object) in Map cannot be applied to (<lambda parameters>)". What to do about this?

Comment: @karleh For which statement?  Are you running Java 8 or 9?

Comment: Forgot to include that this appears for get(k) in 'resources.compute((k, v) -> v - resourcesNeeded.get(k));'. I'm using Java 8 for this project.

Comment: Hmm, it compiles fine for me on the latest version of Intellij.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: How does it compile? You switch variable names (resourcesNeeded vs neededResources) and your compute has different signature from my java8 compute.

Comment: @JanLarsen Where?  It sounds like you're misunderstanding lambdas and their parameters.  `Map#compute` takes the following parameters according to its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ as well. I'll have to try again. Thanks.

Comment: The method compute(String, BiFunction<? super String,? super Integer,? extends Integer>) in the type Map<String,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> k, <no type> v) -> {})

Comment: @JanLarsen `k` and `v` **do not** have *no type*... I recommend you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @karleh I recommend invalidating your caches and restarting Intellij, as well as verifying that your versions of Java and Intellij are up-to-date.  I'll be here if you have any more questions!

Comment: You use `map.compute(function)`. Correct use is `map.compute(key, function)`. `compute` is applied to one key only. You want `replaceAll`, not  `compute`

Comment: @ Jacob G The above is Eclipses response to your compute code line.

Comment: @Arkadiy Good catch, fixed!

Comment: (make sure that the function in replaceAll does the right thing when the resource is not needed (`resourcesNeeded.get(k)` returns `null`)

Comment: Resources: "gold, silver, plutonium". Needed resources: "gold, silver". neededResource.get(plutonium) =  boom.